# data-ng-click not working in template with data-ng-href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

Hi I am new to angular and facing a strange issue with an angular template. My template has code :

```
<li hover-menu data-ng-repeat="nav in navigations" data-ng-class="{'active': current == nav.name.toLowerCase() }">
            <a data-ng-href="{{nav.link}}" data-ng-click="nav.collapse = !nav.collapse">
                <i class="{{nav.icon}} fa-lg-icn"></i><span class="menu-title">{{nav.name}}</span>
            </a>
        <ul class="dropmenu" data-ng-show="nav.sub_menu != false" collapse="nav.collapse">
            <li data-ng-repeat="item in nav.sub_menu">
                <a data-ng-href="{{item.link}}" data-ng-click="showScrollAndGo(item.link)"><i class="fa fa-circle mrm mlm"></i>{{item.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

but here  **data-ng-click="showScrollAndGo(item.link)** is not working. Though I have defined it in global scope like this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
                $rootScope.showScrollAndGo = function (path) {
                    alert(path)
                    $rootScope.showSpinner = false;
                    $location.path(path);
                }
            })
```

Any Idea where I am doing wrong.

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/Vzxjj4vbObGjcZzclmWT?p=preview

Comment: @harsh that one still not working.

Comment: can you put the complete code. your code worked when I tried

Comment: My code was working when I was using it in a simple view like **<li><a href="#/entity/tasks/list" data-ng-click="showScrollAndGo('/entity/contacts/list')"><i class="fa fa-circle mrm mlm"></i>Manage Tasks</a></li>**

Comment: I guess there is some issue with ng-repeat.

Comment: can you make a plunker with complete code

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-ng-href="{{item.link}}" data-ng-click="showScrollAndGo($event, item.link)"><i class="fa fa-circle mrm mlm"></i>{{item.name}}</a>


 $rootScope.showScrollAndGo = function ($event, path) {
                    $event.preventDefault();
                    alert(path)
                    $rootScope.showSpinner = false;
                    $location.path(path);
                }
```

You must prevent the default action of the event as you are on an anchor element and it will trigger the browser to change the view.

Comment: Here **showScrollAndGo** is not being called from view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you better check on requirement. See there are two events that you are trying to do at the same time at the click of anchor tag.

So you let the requirement to be clear that to fire one event at click of anchor tag either to redirect the user to some link or to do some action on click.

When state changes due to of href you not required to take collapse into consideration, because when you come back to the early state/href you will find the collapse to be in early state.

Hope this help!